# MySQL query using ROLLUP gives me an error

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT item, year, SUM(product_sold)
FROM sales2
GROUP BY ROLLUP(item,year);
```

shows an error near ROLLUP using phpmyadmin and MySQL

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you've tried so far and read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Seams like a issues mixing between MSSQL and MySQL syntax ... As it seams you are trying SQL Server (MSSQL) syntax `GROUP BY {
      column-expression  
    | ROLLUP ( <group_by_expression> [ ,...n ] ) ` on a MySQL Server which supports `[GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}, ... [WITH ROLLUP]]`  ....

Comment: ... also besides that not sure how `ROLLUP` is defined in the ANSI/ISO SQL standards, but i find it wierd not seeing `ORDER BY` to be used in the MySQL manual explaining [ROLLUP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html), as implict `ORDER BY` or auto sorting was deprecated in MySQL with `GROUP BY`.. The main reason i find this wierd the SQL language in general is defined to be **orderless** in ANSI/ISO SQL standards

Answer (score 0):

In mysql I think the syntax of the query should be like this

```
select item, year, sum(product_sold) from sales2 group by item, year with rollup;
```